# Rendering a tile map on html5 canvas using and array and fillRect

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas

I'm very much an amateur enthusiast trying to make a basic 2d game map with html canvas. I've done this before by using arrays to create div/img tags and position them. I'm now trying to do this with canvas, not with images but simply drawing squares with fillRect().

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");     
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var map = 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

    window.addEventListener("load", function()
    {
        update();
    }, false);

    function update()
    {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(update, canvas);
        render();
    }

    function render()
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        for(var row = 0; row < map.length; row++)
        {
            for(var column = 0; column < map[0].length; column++)
            {
                switch(map[row][column])
                {
                    case 0: 
                        ctx.fillStyle = #ffffff;
                        ctx.fillRect
                        (
                            row * 64, column * 64, 64, 64
                        );
                        break;

                    case 1: 
                        ctx.fillStyle = #009900;
                        ctx.fillRect
                        (
                            row * 64, column * 64, 64, 64
                        );
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the error: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL' on line 46 which is 'ctx.fillStyle = #ffffff;'.

I'm a bit stuck as to why it's giving this error, I'm wondering if you can't use the context methods in this way with an array but I can't understand why.

If anyone has any advice, I would be very grateful.

Comment: "#ffffff" needs to be inside of a string. It's a string... Javascript cannot directly parse hexcodes that are not in strings. Strings. Stringy strings.

Comment: Oh god how embarrassing, thanks very much!